# How to display a histogram from a queryset in django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, django-views

## AIM

In general, the application displays location data for specific Twitter hashtags. For instance, if the User enters "python". The application searches Twitter for recent tweets containing the hashtag "python" and, where possible, displays location data for those tweets.

Currently, the location data is displayed as a dict, which is achieved through the `def display_locations(self)` function in **Models.py**.

Now, I am attempting to display that data on a histogram. I have written the `draw_histogram()` function in **Views.py** below but I get the error stated below. I suspect that an effective solution may be to call the method: `Hashtag.display_locations` in the function: `draw_histogram()`, but I am not sure.

I have two, alternate, questions:

1. In `draw_histogram()` in **Views.py**, how to set `country_list` to achieve the aim?
2. Perhaps it is more appropriate to include the `draw_histogram()` function as a method in the `class SearchResultsView(generic.ListView)`? If so, how do I do so?

## ERROR

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: draw_histogram() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

## CODE

**Models.py**

```
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a specific Hashtag serch by user """
    search_text = models.CharField(max_length=140, primary_key=True)
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """ String for representing the Model object (search_text) """
        return self.search_text

    def display_locations(self):
        """ Creates a frequency dict of the locations attached to the Hashtag model """
        country_list = list(self.locations.values_list('country', flat=True).all())
        for country in country_list:
            location_freq = {i:country_list.count(i) for i in set(country_list)}
            return location_freq
```

**Views.py**

```
class SearchResultsView(generic.ListView):
    """ Generic class-based view listing search results of locations """
    model = Hashtag
    template_name = 'mapping_twitter/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        """ Restrict the results to the search_text entered on the Form """
        form_input = self.request.GET.get('search_text')
        qs = Hashtag.objects.all().filter(search_text__iexact=form_input)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['search_text', 'locations'] = self.get_queryset()
        return context


def draw_histogram(request, self):
    """ Function to display a histogram of locations associated with the Hashtag """
    country_list = list(self.locations.values_list('country', flat=True).all())
    for country in country_list:
        location_freq = {i:country_list.count(i) for i in set(country_list)}
    plt.bar(list(country_freq.keys()), country_freq.values(), color='g')
    # redirect into the BytesIO object
    f = io.BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(f, format="png", facecolor=(0.95,0.95,0.95))
    plt.clf()
    # Add the contents of the BytesIO object to the response and return
    return HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="image/png")
```

Comment: draw_histogram( self,request)

Comment: @HemanthSP, I have tried as suggested and the following error: `TypeError: draw_histogram() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'`

Comment: Is the `draw_histogram()` an instance method of `SearchResultsView` or just a global function? According to your indent its a global function yet it returns a `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: @Tsang-YiShen, `draw_histogram()` is a global function. I copied the format from here: http://www.extragravity.com/blog/2014/01/04/matplotlib-django/. If you know a way to achieve the aim with `draw_histogram()` as an instance method of `SearchResultsView` that would be fine!